# Qgiscloud upload problems

Tags: qgis, qgis-cloud

Uploading a map to Qgiscloud seems to work fine. But uploading data presents two problems. Qgiscloud complains that my version of OGR/GDAL is outdated. And if I try to upload data, qgis complains that it is unable to open datasource. I'm using Linux Mint 13 and both Qgis 1.8.0 and 1.9.0 on different computers. OGR/GDAL is 1.7.3 and I see no way to update that. Any suggestions? Thanks.